# How to avoid/bypass Python Fernet "InvalidToken"

Tags: python, fernet

I want to decrypt many files and it's working perfectly (encrypt, decrypt).

My problem is that, if any file exists which is not is encrypted, I get an "invalidToken" error message, and the program is unable to decrypt the remaining encrypted files.

Here is my code

```
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import sys
import warnings

InvalidToken = False

key = b'SpecialKindKey'
fernet = Fernet(key)
encr_file_list = []

path ="C:/users/NineTail/desktop/pokemon/go/"
#we shall store all the file names in this list
filelist = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        #append the file name to the list
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file))

#print all the file names
for name in filelist:
    print(name)

for file in filelist:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        file_content = f.read()
        decrypted_content = fernet.decrypt(file_content)
        with open(file, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(decrypted_content)
```

Error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r3.py", line 36, in <module>
    decrypted_content = fernet.decrypt(file_content)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 85, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 121, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a key is already encrypted while using Fernet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137072/how-to-check-if-a-key-is-already-encrypted-while-using-fernet)

Answer (score 2):

Use `try/except` to try to decrypt. If decrypting fails, continue without writing.

```py
...
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet, InvalidToken
...
for file in filelist:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        file_content = f.read()
        try:
            decrypted_content = fernet.decrypt(file_content)
        except InvalidToken:
            continue
        with open(file, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(decrypted_content)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try having a loop that repeats the number of times of files you have, and calls each file separately from the rest

Define a list of files, and store that in a variable
say:

```html
num = #number of files
files = [file1.txt,file2.txt]

    For i in range(num):
      files[num] = open(item, 'r')
      num += 1
```